# How do I use spatial indexes with MySQL 8 without getting error?

Tags: mysql

I get this error:

```
3674 The spatial index on column 'position' will not be used by the
query optimizer since the column does not have an SRID attribute.
Consider adding an SRID attribute to the column.
```

So after reading this article: https://mysqlserverteam.com/geographic-indexes-in-innodb/,
I decided to add SRID to the column, I also tried to read the documentation but I still don't understand what this is. So I do as the text says and add it like this:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `gis`;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gis`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE `gis`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    id           INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname    VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    gender       ENUM('male', 'female') NOT NULL,
    age          TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    position     POINT NOT NULL SRID 4326
);

ALTER TABLE user ADD SPATIAL INDEX(position);
```

And then I try to add some rows:

```
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Alexander', 'male', 34, POINT(63.429909, 10.393035));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Dina', 'female', 21, POINT(63.426300, 10.392481));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Martin', 'male', 32, POINT(63.422304, 10.432027));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Tina', 'female', 19, POINT(63.430603, 10.373038));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Kristin', 'female', 20, POINT(63.434858, 10.411359));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Mette', 'female', 33, POINT(63.420422, 10.403811));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Andres', 'male', 34, POINT(63.419488, 10.395722));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Sandra', 'female', 25, POINT(63.432053, 10.408738));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Kine', 'female', 29, POINT(63.432302, 10.412643));
INSERT INTO user (firstname, gender, age, position) VALUES ('Henrik', 'male', 25, POINT(63.421055, 10.443288));
```

But I get error:

```
Error Code: 3643. The SRID of the geometry does not match the SRID of the column 'position'.
The SRID of the geometry is 0, but the SRID of the column is 4326.
Consider changing the SRID of the geometry or the SRID property of the column.
```

If I remove the SRID then the index does not work when I do a query like this with EXPLAIN:

```
SET @distance = 3.5;
SET @my_place_lng = 63.431592;
SET @my_place_lat = 10.396210;

EXPLAIN SELECT
    id,
    firstname,
    gender,
    age,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(Point(@my_place_lng, @my_place_lat), position) AS distance_from_me
FROM user
WHERE
    ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(
        Point((@my_place_lng+(@distance/111)), (@my_place_lat+(@distance/111))),
        Point((@my_place_lng-(@distance/111)), (@my_place_lat-(@distance/111)))
    ), position)
ORDER BY distance_from_me ASC;
```

What can I do? I don't even know where to read to understand more, haven't seen any examples that I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

specify the SRID value for the geometry, using the `ST_SRID` function i.e.

wrap the point definition

```
... , 34,          POINT(63.429909, 10.393035        ));
```

like this:

```
... , 34, ST_SRID( POINT(63.429909, 10.393035) ,4326) );
          ^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^
```

Note that the SRID value for the geometries will also need to be set in the example query.

MySQL Reference manual says that rather that creating the geometry in SRID 0 and then casting it to SRID 4326, the preferred alternative is to create the geometry in SRID 4326 directly, e.g.

```
... , 34, ST_PointFromText('POINT(63.429909, 10.393035)',4326) ));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^
```

---

If we don't want to do that, then another (less desirable) alternative would be to set the SRID value of the column to the default value 0 rather than 4326. When we don't set the SRID value, MySQL uses the default value of 0. But then we'd be working in unitless flat plane coordinate system. That's not good if we want the POINT geometry to be handled as GPS earth degrees latitude/longitude coordinates.

---

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_st-srid

Comment: I had to remove the comma to make it work.